# Why do I have this Internal Server Error in Blazer (Rails Business Intelligence gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, business-intelligence, blazer

(I almost posted this as an issue for Blazer but managed to figure out the problem. I'm posting it here in case someone else has the same issue.)

## Bad Data Checks

For any and all bad_data checks that should "fail" (i.e. trigger the alert state and therefore the e-mail message) on my production server I get "Internal Server Error" as soon as I save them, where you would normally see "FAILING" or "PASSING":

[image]

## Missing Data Checks

The same is true for missing_data checks that should "fail":

[image]

Everything else works perfectly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that my production server only had the `default_url_options[:host]` configured for `routes` and not for `action_mailer`.  You need to have something like this in `config/environments/<environment_name>.rb`

```
  ...
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {host: "https://blah-blah-blah.whatever"}
  config.action_mailer.asset_host = "https://blah-blah-blah.whatever"
  ...
```

(The `asset_host` may not strictly be necessary.  I didn't test without it.)